# Why does my html p element appear on top?

Tags: html, css

The paragraph element is under the div element in the code but over the div element in the website.
Also my headline turn white when i delete position:fixed;
What is wrong with my code ?

I tried aligning things but it didn`t work

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.headline {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #14213D;
  position: fixed;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.logo p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fcab11;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>Muttis kurs</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>hello</p>
```

Comment: it's the position fixed makes it cover. try position sticky, or add padding-top to body of 100px

Answer (score 1):

Setting `position:fixed` removes the element from the normal document flow. You need to accommodate for this.

```css
body {
  margin:0px;
  /*Accomodate height of headline*/
  padding-top:100px;
}

.headline {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #14213D;
  position: fixed;
  /*Acnhor headling to top*/
  top:0;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.logo p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #fcab11;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>Muttis kurs</p>
  </div>
</div>
<p>hello</p>
```